# C# async/await with HttpClient GetAsync - non-async calling method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Here is an async/await when calling from a main function which cannot be marked async - the function *must* run synchronously, but because HttpClient is async, at some point, the await has to make things stop gracefully. I've read a lot about how `.Result` or `.Wait` can cause deadlocks, but those are the only versions that actually make the code synchronous.

Here is an example program, roughly following what the code does - note the 4 attempts in the loop - only one of them actually puts data out in the correct order. Is there something fundamentally wrong with this structure/can I not use example #3?

The closest example I can find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583998/async-await-in-foreach-with-httpclient)  and that is where the calling function can be made async, which this one cannot. I've tried making `private static void Process()` an async and calling it with `Task.Run(async ()=> await Process());` but it still runs out of order. The only thing that consistently works is `Wait/Result` which can deadlock, particularly with HttpClient from what I've read. Any thoughts?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestAsync
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1. Calling process at {0:mm.ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);

            // Call 1
            Process();

            Console.WriteLine("1. Calling process at {0:mm.ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);

            // Call 2
            Process();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Process()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2. Calling CallAsyncTest at {0:mm.ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);

            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            {
                // Try 1 - doesn't work
                //CallAsyncTest(i);

                // Try 2 - doesn't work
                //Task.Run(async () => await CallAsyncTest(i));

                // Try 3 - but works not recommended
                CallAsyncTest(i).Wait();

                // Try 4 - doesn't work
                //CallAsyncTest(i).ConfigureAwait(false); ;
            }
        }

        private static async Task CallAsyncTest(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}. Calling await AsyncTest.Start at {1:mm.ss.fff}", i + 2, DateTime.Now);

            var x = await AsyncTest.Start(i);
        }
    }

    public class AsyncTest
    {
        public static async Task<string> Start(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}. Calling await Post<string> at {1:mm.ss.fff}", i + 3, DateTime.Now);

            return await Post<string>(i);
        }

        private static async Task<T> Post<T>(int i)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()))
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.google.com"))
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        string responseString = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            

        Console.WriteLine("response");
                }
            }

        }

        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use async Main? Refer to <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main>.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529061/whats-the-right-way-to-use-httpclient-synchronously) can help?

Comment: @Saar OP says that function calling `HttpClient` can not be async, so making `Main` async is pointless in this case. Also it seems that this is just testing/reproducing code, not actual one.

Comment: Also you can call `Wait` on the resulting task in you second attempt (i.e. `var t = Task.Run(async () => await CallAsyncTest(i)); t.Wait();`, see [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/jpsanders/asp-net-do-not-use-task-result-in-main-context)).  It should be less dangerous and should give you needed result.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it carefully. So, the questions becomes: How to do a sync over async correctly. By reading the question, we already know there's pitfalls. Let me try it again: Could you please explain why can't you make the caller async? :-)

Answer (score 1):

> but those are the only versions that actually make the code synchronous

Exactly, you shouldn't use it for that reason alone. You don't want to lock your main thread while you perform I/O or your application is in the most literal sense trash.

If you don't want to make your entire application `async`-aware for whatever reason, you can still use proper `async` patterns. Remember that `await` is nothing but syntactic sugar around what the `Task` class already provides you: a way to continue after a task is complete.

So instead of having your process function lock your main thread, you can set up a daisy chain of `.ContinueWith()` on your four calls (if they're supposed to run in sequence) or on a `Task.WhenAll` (if they're supposed to run in parallel) and return immediately. The continuation then takes care of updating your UI with the data received (if successful) or error information (if it failed).

Answer (score 1):

> the function must run synchronously

As others have noted, the *best* solutions are to go [async all the way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). But I'll assume that there's a good reason why this isn't possible.

> at some point, the await has to make things stop gracefully.

At some point, your code will have to block on the asynchronous code, yes.

> I've read a lot about how .Result or .Wait can cause deadlocks, but those are the only versions that actually make the code synchronous.

Right. Blocking on asynchronous code is the only way to make it synchronous.

It's not actually about `Result` or `Wait` per se - it's *any* kind of blocking. And there are some situations where [blocking on asynchronous code will cause deadlocks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Specifically, when all of these conditions are true:

1. The asynchronous code [captures a context](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). `await` does capture contexts by default.
2. The calling code blocks a thread in that context.
3. The context only allows one thread at a time. E.g., UI thread contexts or legacy ASP.NET request contexts only allow one thread at a time.

Console applications and ASP.NET Core applications do not have a context, so a deadlock will not happen in those scenarios.

> The only thing that consistently works is Wait/Result which can deadlock... Any thoughts?

There are [some hacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development) you can choose from to block on asynchronous code.

One of them is just to block directly. This works fine for Console / ASP.NET Core applications (because they don't have a context that would cause the deadlock). I recommend using `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in this case to avoid exception wrappers that come when using `Result` / `Wait()`:

```
CallAsyncTest(i).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

However, that approach will not work if the application is a UI app or legacy ASP.NET app. In that case, you can push the asynchronous work off to a thread pool thread and block on *that*. The thread pool thread runs outside the context and so it avoids the deadlock, but this hack means that `CallAsyncTest` *must* be able to be run on a thread pool thread - no accessing UI elements or `HttpContext.Current` or anything else that depends on the context, because the context won't be there:

```
Task.Run(() => CallAsyncTest(i)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

There is no solution that works in every scenario. Blocking directly works if there isn't a context (e.g., Console apps). Blocking on `Task.Run` works if the code can run on an arbitrary thread pool thread. There are a few other hacks available but those two are the most common.

Here's why the other attempts failed.

This one starts the task but doesn't wait at all:

```
// Try 1 - doesn't work
CallAsyncTest(i);
```

This one starts the task in a thread pool thread but doesn't wait at all:

```
// Try 2 - doesn't work
Task.Run(async () => await CallAsyncTest(i));
```

"Try 4" is exactly the same as "Try 1". The call to `ConfigureAwait` does nothing because there is no `await` to configure. So it also just starts the task but doesn't wait at all:

```
// Try 4 - doesn't work
CallAsyncTest(i).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: @Steve, instead of using `Task.Run` wouldn't capturing the current context, setting the current context to `null`, executing the blocking code and restoring the current context work?

Comment: @PauloMorgado: The "context" is `SynchronizationContext.Current` *or* `TaskScheduler.Current` - that second part is often forgotten. You can set `SynchronizationContext.Current` to `null`, but the easiest way to get a default `TaskScheduler.Current` is to run the code on a thread pool thread.

Answer (score 0):

Why not making the Process method async, and then use the normal async await pattern?

The Process signature would be

```
private static async Task Process()
```

That would allow you to use `await CallAsyncTest(i)`

and you would Wait it on the main method, like so:

```
Process.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This would be the equivalent to the implementation of async main introduced in C# 7.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main#detailed-design

Comment: This just moves the problem one level up, but it's ultimately equally susceptible to deadlocks as using `.Wait()` or `.Result` directly on the `HttpClient` call.

Comment: No, it will block the main thread, not the one used to make the HTTP request.

Comment: [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) making the HTTP request, it's a pure I/O task and won't block or create any thread. Waiting without an explicit `await` is simply a bad practice potentially leading to deadlocks. That's why `async Main` was introduced.

Comment: @Alejandro you do realize that he is awaiting the httpClient.GetAsync call, right?